# How to get a text which is dynamically changed by JavaScript in Java+Selenium?

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an element with `id="time"`. The value of this element is a time (in "hh:ss" format) which is dynamically changed (by using a JavaScript script called `timer()`):

Some code of the site:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var time = {"m":59,"s":59};

            function timer() {
                if (time['s'] < 0) {
                    time['s'] = 59;
                    time['m']--;
                }
                if (time['m'] == 0 && time['s'] == 0) {
                   //do something
                } else {
                    if (time['s'].toString().length == 2) {
                        return time['m'] + ':' + time['s']--;
                    } else {
                        return time['m'] + ':0' + time['s']--;
                    }
                }
            }

            time = document.getElementById('time')
            setInterval('time.innerHTML=timer()', 1e3)
        </script>
    <head>
<body>
    (...)
    <span id="time"></span>
    (...)
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I want to get **the current value of the element** in Java using Selenium-WebDriver.
I've tried to do it simple by `getText()` or `getAttribute("innerHTML")` of the span element, like this:

```
String time = driver.findElement(By.id("time")).getText();
```

or

```
String time = driver.findElement(By.id("time")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

But it doesn't work - `time` is an an empty string in these both cases.

Then I've tried it with using JavaScript in Selenium:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String time = (String) js.executeScript("return document.getElementById('time').innerHTML;");
```

But `time` is also an empty string.

Script executing in FireBug console returns correct value, eg.:

```
>>> document.getElementById("time").innerHTML;
"58:20"
```

So... how to get a current value in Selenium?

Comment: Since `setInterval` is going to execute that `function` after X seconds, then your script is going to need to wait for that same amount of time too. This is probably your issue, the test is asking for the `innerHTML` **before** it's been updated by the `function`.

Comment: @Arran, thanks for your comment! It helped me very much. After loading the page I am waiting just a one second (by using sleep()) and now every way of getting a value works correctly.